# Running jQuery UI with Draggable and Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am working on **[this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/LEwg8/147/)**. Why am I not able to run the draggable and droppable using jQuery UI? I am not getting any error message on console.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$(function() {
    $(".draggable").draggable();
    $(".item").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var $this = $(this);
            var width = $(".item").width();
            var height = $(".item").height();
            var cntrLeft = (width / 2) - ( $(".draggable").width() / 2);
            var cntrTop = (height / 2) - ( $(".draggable").height() / 2);

           $(".draggable").css({
                left: cntrLeft + "px",
                top: cntrTop + "px"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: At first glance, you aren't including Jquery UI, which is a requirement for `draggable` and `droppable`

Comment: Also, you are missing an end quote after 'item' on your last 'item' div.

Comment: Take a peek at this and see what you think http://jsfiddle.net/LEwg8/153/

Answer (score 0):

You must include `jQuery UI 1.10.3` to use drag and drop. By default they are not included in the jQuery library.

*Check the box on the upper left of the interface for `jQuery UI 1.10.3` to add the reference.*

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bghvntvz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to load the jquery UI framework. On panel, under "Frameworks and Extensions", make sure jquery UI is checked.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/LEwg8/152/

Here is a (kind of) working jsfiddle that you can build off of.

Using broad selectors e.g. `$('.item')` inside of an event callback like you are doing is a recipe for disaster. With jQuery you can almost always get the relevant event elements from the event object.